# how to pick up value of a pixel from a mouse click?

Tags: c++, opencv

I show a Mat matrix on the screen as an image.
I want to click a location on this image and I want obtain that pixel value on screen.

How can be done with OpenCV, C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for cv::Mat it would look like:

```
cv::Mat mat; // load img, etc

cv::setMouseCallback("Test", my_mouse_callback, (void*) &mat);

// ...



void my_mouse_callback(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param){
  cv::Mat mat = *((cv::Mat*)param);  // so, 1st cast, then deref
}
```

Comment: there is still a problem: how can I display image.at<uchar>(y,x) where x,y is the clicked point????

Comment: you could just write to the pixel: image.at<uchar>(y,x) = 255;

Answer (score 2):

I use this code below for `IplImage`, but the result should be the same when you use `Mat`.

```
void my_mouse_callback(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param){
  IplImage* image = (IplImage*) param;

  switch(event) {
    case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
      std::cout << "x: " << x << std::endl;
      std::cout << "y: " << y << std::endl;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}

int main() {
  IplImage* image = cvLoadImage("picture_file_name_here");

  cvNamedWindow("Test");

  cvSetMouseCallback("Test", my_mouse_callback, (void*) image);

  cvShowImage("Test", image);
  cvWaitKey(0);

  cvReleaseImage(&image);

  return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you help me to change it to handle Mat objects??